# How to change the default global value of left padding in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4, css-variables

I want to change the default value of global left ion-padding.

Adding `--ion-padding-start: 20px` in variable.scss under :root selector is not working. I don't want to explicit mention the left padding to the components, as doing this applies the left padding. I want to set the value for global left padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--ion-padding-start will not work if we want to change the default value of padding. I added these lines of code in global.scss file :

```
.ion-padding,
  [padding] {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
  }
```

In this way we can change the default value of global left padding in ionic project.

Answer (score 0):

Globally you can change only --ion-padding, now not support for --ion-padding-start: 20px 
You have to manually change all component level or particular scss file for page
--ion-padding-start: 20px